# NCrunch doesn't mark lines as covered by tests, but they are

Tags: code-coverage, ncrunch

I have just started using NCrunch and have some classes where the markers show there is no coverage, but I have tests which NCrunch is running successfully.

When I edit the class (just add a space) the markers go green for a short while, then return to black. Why might this be?

Comment: Have you asked this on the NCrunch forums/mailing list?

Comment: @ShaunWilde yeah, I cross posted here just in case

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen today and just a simple VS restart fixed it.  You can also try resync button which is the 6th from the left of the NCrunch Tests window.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem based on the description.  It also appeared to affect coverage stats as well as the visual markers.  I was running NCrunch 1.39.15b on VS2010.  Re-syncing and reloading VS2010 did not fix it.  I eventually uninstalled NCrunch and upgraded to 1.41.0.50 and the problem went away.  It might have been a bug in NCrunch, but I'm not sure.  At any rate, try upgrading your NCrunch installation and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah I had cross posted this to the NCrunch website and I think that the functionality to support this was added in a later version.  Unfortunately I have moved jobs since having this issue so can't test it now, as I don't have the same setup in the new job.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, try to delete *NCrunch*{SolutionName} folder inside a project, solved an issue for me.